# Manipulation of a plot computed in several steps

Tags: plotting, manipulate

the following test works for fixed parameter si:

```
 test = Block[{si = 2}, 
       k = si s^2 + 107 s/5  + 10  ((1 + s)^(-2) - 1) - 1/10;
       cr = Chop[N[Solve[k == 0, s], 12]];
       Wsa = Apart[(1 + s)^2/(si Product[s - (s /. cr[[i]]), 
       {i,4}])];
       Wp[y_] := D[InverseLaplaceTransform[Wsa, s, x], x] /.x-> 
        y];
    Plot[Evaluate[Wp[x]], {x, 0, 16}]
```

Turning it to Manipulate results in infinite evaluation on 11.3, and messages
General::ivar: 0.0003268571428571428` is not a valid variable. Help?

```
k = si s^2 + 107 s/5  + 10  ((1 + s)^(-2) - 1) - 1/10;
Manipulate[cr = Chop[N[Solve[k == 0, s], 12]];
 Wsa = Apart[(1 + s)^2/(si Product[s - (s /. cr[[i]]), {i, 1, 4}])];
 Wp[y_] := D[InverseLaplaceTransform[Wsa, s, x], x] /. x -> y;
 Plot[Evaluate[Wp[x]] /. {si -> s2}, {x, 0, 16}], {{s2, 1, "s2"}, 1, 
  2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that may be useful.  For clarity, let's obtain an expression for $W_p$ by evaluating the following:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
wsa = (1 + s)^2/(si  q);
q = (s - cr1) (s - cr2) (s - cr3) (s - cr4);
wp = D[InverseLaplaceTransform[wsa, s, x], x]
```

The values for $C_{r1} ... C_{r4}$ are obtained here:

```
k = si s^2 + 107 s/5 + 10 ((1 + s)^(-2) - 1) - 1/10;
cr = {cr1, cr2, cr3, cr4} = s /. Solve[k == 0, s];
```

The list `cr` just makes it easy to insert intermediate steps like `cr /. si->1.5`.  Now we can create a plot and adjust the plot range to cover a range of `si` values

```
Plot[Evaluate[Chop[wp /. si -> Range[1, 2, 1/3]]],
 {x, 0, 16},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {0.0225, .0275}}]
```

[image]

The manipualate is slow, taking several seconds to regenerate the plot, so we use later steps for the slider variable, $\lambda$

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Chop[wp /. si -> λ], {x, 0, 16},
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {0.0225, .0275}}],
 {{λ, 1.5}, 1, 2, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The manipulate works, but slowly.  The gridlines make is easier to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the first plot  was like  a warmup; or, the fact  of computing those values  helps somehow to spped the manipulate ?

Comment: @florin  The first plot shows the scale required for me to see the changes effected by `Manipulate`.  At first I used a 0-0.1 scale and thought the function was independent of $s_i$, or that I had made a mistake.  The first plot shows what kind of changes to expect the slider to produce, like a proof of concept.  It also shows that complex values should (probably) not be the issue, if something does go wrong in the `Manipulate` version.